# SQL Server Compact 3.5 for VS 2012

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I have installed Sql Server Compact 3.5 on my machine. But still not appearing on Visual Studio 2012 when trying to add new data source. What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there's native support, but I don't have a VS 2012 installation handy to confirm. You may way to check out this Codeplex project, though:

http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/

Comment: No, 3.5 is no longer supported in Server Explorer in VS 2012 (no DDEX provider)

Comment: @hatem sales: It shows up in my VS2010 instance, but it does look like it's not supported in 2012. In any case, the codeplex project I linked to will provide at least some of the missing functionality. Alternatively, you could use SSMS 2008 to manage your database.

Comment: The latest version of my Toolbox add-in add a simple 3.5 DDEX provider to enable EF support for 3.5 in VS 2012 and later